# Aggregating Rows into a Single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I am having trouble aggregating a table down into a single row for each customer, the table contains bookings but has duplicate records for different parts of the booking like flight, accommodation, tax, transfer that sort of thing.

I know what columns I have to group by but I just cant seem to get it right 
This is what I have so far:

BkgAgentLut
this is a lookup table that contains a single record for each filename and sheet name as filename could have two different sheet names, it brings back a system name which I need to use to define what files im using for that aggregation.

AdvBookings
This is the raw data table that holds the bookings this has to be split into different aggregations I.E( those files that use Micro as its system, those that use Vantage as its system) this is because the two different systems require diofferent group by clauses due to the raw data.

```
SELECT
Min(URN), 
MAX(CAST(bookingdate AS integer)),
MAX(CAST(departuredate AS integer)),
MAX([IdentityValue]) AS [IdentityValue],
MAX(B.[FileName]) AS [FileName],
MAX(B.[SheetName]) AS [SheetName],
MAX([LineNum]) AS [LineNum],
MAX([Title]) AS [Title],
MAX([FirstName]) AS [FirstName],
MAX([Initial]) AS [Initial],
MAX([Surname]) AS [Surname],
MAX([NameLine]) AS [NameLine],
MAX([Addr1]) AS [Addr1],
MAX([Addr2]) AS [Addr2],
MAX([Addr3]) AS [Addr3],
MAX([Addr4]) AS [Addr4],
MAX([Addr5]) AS [Addr5],
MAX([HouseNo]) AS [HouseNo],
MAX([City]) AS [City],
MAX([County]) AS [County],
MAX([Postcode]) AS [Postcode],
MAX([TelNo1]) AS [TelNo1],
MAX([TelNo2]) AS [TelNo2],
SUM(CAST(TotalCost AS MONEY)) AS  TotalCost,
NettCost = NULL,
Paid = NULL,
Balance = NULL,
Discount = NULL,
Commission = NULL,
MAX(Adults) AS Adults,
MAX(Children) AS Children,
MAX(Infants) AS Infants,
MAX(Duration) AS Duration,
MAX(PAX) AS PAX,
SUM(CAST(Duration AS INT)) AS Duration,
MAX([DPA1]) AS [DPA1],
MAX([DPA2]) AS [DPA2],
MAX([PrimaryCode]) AS [PrimaryCode],
MAX([SEG]) AS [SEG],
MAX([Month]) AS [Month],
MAX([DeparturePoint]) AS [DeparturePoint],
MAX([ArrivalPoint]) AS [ArrivalPoint],
MAX([HolidayType]) AS [HolidayType],
MAX([TertiaryCode]) AS [TertiaryCode],
MAX([SubTertiaryCode]) AS [SubTertiaryCode],
MAX([Season]) AS [Season],
MAX([HQABTA]) AS [HQABTA],
MAX([BranchABTA]) AS [BranchABTA],
MAX([Company]) AS [Company],
MAX([Clerk]) AS [Clerk],
MAX([FirstRef]) AS [FirstRef],
MAX([SecondRef]) AS [SecondRef],
MAX([Board]) AS [Board],
MAX([EmailAddress]) AS [EmailAddress],
MAX([Direct]) AS [Direct],
MAX([Division]) AS [Division],
MAX([LeadPaxAge]) AS [LeadPaxAge],
MAX([DueDate]) AS [DueDate],
MAX([PreferredMailing]) AS [PreferredMailing],
MAX([Confidential]) AS [Confidential],
MAX([InsuranceNote]) AS [InsuranceNote],
MAX([DOB]) AS [DOB],
MAX([LastDestination]) AS [LastDestination],
MAX([Pax_DOBS]) AS [Pax_DOBS],
MAX([PaymentMethods]) AS [PaymentMethods],
MAX([AirportName]) AS [AirportName],
MAX([Resort]) AS [Resort],
MAX([Hotel]) AS [Hotel],
MAX([HotelLine2]) AS [HotelLine2],
MAX([RoomType]) AS [RoomType],
MAX([PreviousBookings]) AS [PreviousBookings],
MAX([PreviousTravels]) AS [PreviousTravels],
MAX([DestinationList]) AS [DestinationList],
MAX([Tour]) AS [Tour],
MAX([Description]) AS [Description],
MAX([Gender]) AS [Gender],
MAX([TransactionNo]) AS [TransactionNo],
MAX([TransactionType]) AS [TransactionType],
MAX([BusAcctRef]) AS [BusAcctRef],
MAX([BookingStatus]) AS [BookingStatus],
MAX([BranchName]) AS [BranchName],
MAX([OperName]) AS [OperName]
FROM AdvBookings B
LEFT JOIN BkgAgentLut A 
ON B.FileName = A.FileName 
AND B.SheetName = A.SheetName 
WHERE A.[Res System] = 'Vantage'
GROUP BY    title, 
    firstname, 
    Surname, 
    addr1, 
    Addr2, 
    Addr3, 
    Addr4, 
    Postcode,
    BookingDate,  -- THIS NEEDS TO BE TURNED INTO AN INTEGER SO i CAN USE IT AS A GROUP BY
    Departuredate -- THIS NEEDS TO BE TURNED INTO AN INTEGER SO i CAN USE IT AS A GROUP BY
ORDER BY FileName
```

**Tables:**

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdvBookings](
        [IdentityValue] [int] NOT NULL,
        [FileName] [varchar](55) NOT NULL,
        [SheetName] [varchar](49) NOT NULL,
        [LineNum] [int] NOT NULL,
        [BookingDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [URN] [varchar](8) NULL,
        [Title] [varchar](25) NULL,
        [FirstName] [varchar](30) NULL,
        [Initial] [varchar](5) NULL,
        [Surname] [varchar](38) NULL,
        [NameLine] [varchar](41) NULL,
        [Addr1] [varchar](58) NULL,
        [Addr2] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Addr3] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Addr4] [varchar](45) NULL,
        [Addr5] [varchar](48) NULL,
        [HouseNo] [varchar](5) NULL,
        [City] [varchar](25) NULL,
        [County] [varchar](31) NULL,
        [Postcode] [varchar](19) NULL,
        [TelNo1] [varchar](40) NULL,
        [TelNo2] [varchar](37) NULL,
        [DPA1] [varchar](12) NULL,
        [DPA2] [varchar](4) NULL,
        [TotalCost] [varchar](19) NULL,
        [NettCost] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [Paid] [varchar](8) NULL,
        [Balance] [varchar](8) NULL,
        [Discount] [varchar](8) NULL,
        [Commission] [varchar](10) NULL,
        [PrimaryCode] [varchar](7) NULL,
        [Adults] [varchar](10) NULL,
        [Children] [varchar](7) NULL,
        [Infants] [varchar](2) NULL,
        [Pax] [varchar](7) NULL,
        [SEG] [varchar](3) NULL,
        [DepartureDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [Month] [varchar](19) NULL,
        [DeparturePoint] [varchar](22) NULL,
        [ArrivalPoint] [varchar](25) NULL,
        [HolidayType] [varchar](27) NULL,
        [TertiaryCode] [varchar](7) NULL,
        [SubTertiaryCode] [varchar](7) NULL,
        [Season] [varchar](3) NULL,
        [HQABTA] [varchar](7) NULL,
        [BranchABTA] [varchar](14) NULL,
        [Duration] [varchar](47) NULL,
        [Company] [varchar](64) NULL,
        [Clerk] [varchar](8) NULL,
        [FirstRef] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [SecondRef] [varchar](20) NULL,
        [Board] [varchar](51) NULL,
        [EmailAddress] [varchar](150) NULL,
        [Direct] [varchar](66) NULL,
        [Division] [varchar](7) NULL,
        [LeadPaxAge] [varchar](4) NULL,
        [DueDate] [varchar](19) NULL,
        [PreferredMailing] [varchar](10) NULL,
        [Confidential] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [InsuranceNote] [varchar](21) NULL,
        [DOB] [datetime] NULL,
        [LastDestination] [varchar](42) NULL,
        [Pax_DOBS] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [PaymentMethods] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [AirportName] [varchar](15) NULL,
        [Resort] [varchar](52) NULL,
        [Hotel] [varchar](180) NULL,
        [HotelLine2] [varchar](49) NULL,
        [RoomType] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [PreviousBookings] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [PreviousTravels] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [DestinationList] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [Tour] [varchar](36) NULL,
        [Description] [varchar](169) NULL,
        [Gender] [varchar](6) NULL,
        [TransactionNo] [varchar](4) NULL,
        [TransactionType] [varchar](35) NULL,
        [BusAcctRef] [varchar](6) NULL,
        [BookingStatus] [varchar](10) NULL,
        [BranchName] [varchar](62) NULL,
        [OperName] [varchar](50) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO                      


        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BkgAgentLut](
            [FileName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
            [SheetName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
            [Agent] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
            [ABTA] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
            [FileName_Rule] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
            [Agent_Identification_Rule] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
            [ShortName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
            [Res System] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
            [ResID] [int] NULL
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Sample Data** for AdvBookings

```
IdentityValue,FileName,SheetName,LineNum,BookingDate,URN,Title,FirstName,Initial,Surname,NameLine,Addr,Addr2,Addr3,Addr4,Addr5,HouseNo,City,County,PosNcode,TelNo1,TelNo8,DPA1,DPA2,TotalCost,NettCost,Paid,Balance,Discount,Commission,PrimaryCode,Adults,Children,Infants,Pax,SEG,DepartureDate,Month,DeparturePoint,ArrivalPoint,HolidayType,TertiaryCode,SubTertiaryCode,Season,HQABTA,BranchABTA,Duration,Company,Clerk,FirstRef,SecondRef,Board,EmailAddress,Direct,Division,LeadPaxAge,DueDate,PreferredMailing,Confidential,InsuranceNote,DOB,LastDestination,Pax_DOBS,PaymentMethods,AirportName,Resort,Hotel,HotelLine2,RoomType,PreviousBookings,PreviousTravels,DestinationList,Tour,Description,Gender,TransactionNo,TransactionType,BusAcctRef,BookingStatus,BranchName,OperName
145990,ATE_L389X_20140902044749.CSV,ATE_L389X_20140902044749.CSV,1,00:00.0,385221,Mr,W,W,Sousa,NULL, David Moon Hosue,Devonshire Place,St Helier,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,KE2 3DP,864886,07797 748 173 Daught,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,0,0,1,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,JER,FNC,Summer Sun,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,L389X,14,ESTR,NULL,NULL,NULL,<No BoardBasis Defined>,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Funchal,Residencial Parque,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Portugal,NULL,NULL,Male,2,Package Holiday,NULL,D,Bellingham Travel St Helier,Estrela Travel
1410709,ATE_Howard_20140901162839.CSV,ATE_Howard_20140901162839.CSV,1,00:00.0,8866,Mr,W,W,Coward,NULL, Southwood Road,Trowbridge,Wiltshire,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,BA647BZ,01885 666638,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,2,0,4,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Cruise,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,92943,NULL,MCRU,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,carol.coward@blueyonder.co.uk,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Male,4,Cruise,NULL,D,Howard Travel,Misc Cruise
470590,AdvantageData 31 August.xlsx,'CBT Travel$',1,49:59.0,5035,Mr.,q,q,Hudson,NULL, Harlech Close,Haslingden,Rossendale,Lancashire,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,BB4 6NL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1729,1653,NULL,NULL,76,NULL,NULL,2,0,0,NULL,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,11,Royal Caribbean Cruise Line,NULL,NULL,NULL,Full Board,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,N,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Eastern Caribbean,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
496438,ALTHAMS_20140907.csv,ALTHAMS_20140907.csv,1,00:00.0,2004019,Mr,D,D,Cooper,NULL, Ullswater Close,Rishton,Blackburn,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,BB64EP,1854888480,NULL,Y,N,2206.24,NULL,2206.24,0,NULL,265.74,CNT,2,0,NULL,2,TP,00:00.0,Sep,MANCHESTER,NULL,NULL,REG,NULL,S10,11626,NULL,14,THOMSON,CT1,2771894,NULL,HB,NULL,NULL,ACC,65,06/07/2010,P,N,INSURANCE ISSUED,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SANTORINI,VENUS BEACH,NULL,1 DOUBL3  SH WC BL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
1455951,ATE_C5649_20140903155313.CSV,ATE_C5649_20140903155313.CSV,1,00:00.0,64512,Mr,W,W,O Donnell,NULL, Derrycarib Road,NULL,Portadown,Co Armagh,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,BN62 6UY,NULL,7716080365,NULL,NULL,12,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,0,0,1,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Summer Sun,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,C5649,NULL,MISC,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Male,2,Misc Item,NULL,D,Terra - C5649,Misc Account - Ukl Bookings
329035,HOLIDAYTVL_20140907.csv,HOLIDAYTVL_20140907.csv,1,00:00.0,1065539,Mr,PATRICK,P,Moody,NULL, Tennyson Avenue,Bridlington,East Yorkshire,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,YO65 2EX,6866661564,NULL,N,N,523,NULL,523,0,NULL,62.76,BCH,1,0,NULL,1,ST,00:00.0,Jun,TON,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,S10,35404,35404,7,SHEARINGS,RLH,M13291,NULL,HALF BOARD,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,27/03/2010,P,N,INS. DECLINED,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"OBAN,MULL & IONA",GREAT WESTERN,NULL,SINGLE ROOM WITH A SEA VIEW,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
396525,REGAL_20140907.csv,REGAL_20140907.csv,1,00:00.0,1070979,Mrs,JANET,W,Hoskins,NULL, St David'S Close,Wild Mill,Bridgend,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,CF36 6RR,01656 658865,NULL,N,N,1106.55,NULL,1078,0,NULL,97.73,SSU,2,0,NULL,2,TP,00:00.0,Jul,"CARDIFF,UK",NULL,NULL,BUS,NULL,S10,71538,71538,10,THOMAS COOK,CLA,T122485N,       BUS,HALF BOARD,NULL,NULL,NULL,46,02/05/2010,P,N,JTI10A-38338146,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,MONASTIR,ROYAL KENZ,NULL,1 TWIN3 B S WC BAL/TER : PORT EL KANTAOUI,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Regal Travel - 71538,NULL
417902,TicketsAnywhere_20140831.tab,TicketsAnywhere_20140831.tab,1,00:00.0,100,Mrs,Tanya,NULL,Farrer,NULL, Merton Road,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Princes Risborough,Bucks,PP27 0DR,0660 943 8015,NULL,NULL,NULL,18.5,18.5,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,8932X,0,Ultrasun Sun cream,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Ultrasun sun cream,NULL,NULL,Ultrasun Sun cream,NULL
437608,TRAVELTIMEWORLD_20140907.csv,TRAVELTIMEWORLD_20140907.csv,1,00:00.0,3012302,Miss,LYNN,L,Guthrie,NULL,Nb Crystal,White Lion Wharf,Star Tops End Marsworth,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,PP23 4LK,1448,7756854687,N,N,541.9,NULL,541.9,0,NULL,27.6,LHV,1,0,NULL,1,ST,00:00.0,Feb,LH4,NULL,NULL,RPT,NULL,L,F2256,F2256,70,JETSET,ASH,3268399,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,02/01/2010,P,N,CLIENT DECLINED,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,ACCRA,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
447594,AdvantageData 31 August.xlsx,'Apex Rhuddlan$',1,56:23.0,6618,Mrs.,C,C,Morris,NULL, Heol Hendre,Rhuddlan,Denbighshire,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,LL68 5PG,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,418,418,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,2,0,0,NULL,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,4,Alfa Travel Ltd,NULL,NULL,NULL,Half Board,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,N,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Vardiff And The Valleys,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Alfa Travel - Free Insurance Offer,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
457205,AdvantageData 31 August.xlsx,'Baldwins Tenterden $',1,39:56.0,56,Mr.,P,P,Sabin,NULL,Woodcote,Woodchurch Road,Tenterden,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NN30 7AD,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,3412.98,3362.98,NULL,NULL,50,NULL,NULL,2,0,0,NULL,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,16,Celebrity Cruises,NULL,NULL,NULL,Full Board,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,N,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Exotic Southern Caribbean,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
457821,AdvantageData 31 August.xlsx,'Baldwins Tonbridge$',1,04:03.0,14179,Mr.,K,K,Hill,NULL,Lodge Farm Oast,Bramble Reed Lane,Matfield,Kent,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NN62 7EN,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,5239,5239,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,2,2,0,NULL,NULL,30:00.0,NULL,LGW,PVK,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,14,Travelux Ltd,NULL,NULL,NULL,Self Catering,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,N,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Villa Votsalo,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Greece / Lefkada,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
285347,CH Advantage_Report upto 31aug14.tab,CH Advantage_Report upto 31aug14.tab,1,00:00.0,7785,Mr,Mark,NULL,Saunders,NULL, Whitehall Road,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Toronto,Ontario,M4W 2C5,14166886488,NULL,NULL,NULL,60,60,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,4,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,K4373,0,Out`N`About,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,linda.saunders@rogers.com,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Airport transfers,NULL,NULL,Out`N`About,NULL
81365,ATE_56665_20140902040159.CSV,ATE_56665_20140902040159.CSV,1,00:00.0,1295,Mrs,W,W,Green,NULL,C/O Mr & Mrs P Wanstall,2 Wellfield,Hartley,Kent,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,DA3 7EQ,01464 606 915,7957830380,NULL,NULL,2304,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,0,0,2,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,LGW,HOG,Longhaul,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,56665,14,TCH,NULL,NULL,NULL,<No BoardBasis Defined>,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Playa Pesquero,Hotel Playa Pesquero,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Cuba,NULL,NULL,Female,1,Bonded Package,NULL,D,Sunways Travel,Thomas Cook Holidays
1056744,ATE_L3885_20140902045317.CSV,ATE_L3885_20140902045317.CSV,1,00:00.0,388377,Ms,Ann,A,Shanahan,NULL, Landscape Grove,St Helier,Jersey,Channel Islands,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,KE2 3KU,644168,077977 44186,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,4,0,0,4,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,<No Type Defined>,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,L3885,3,SBK,NULL,NULL,NULL,<No BoardBasis Defined>,ann.shanahan@bedellgroup.com        ann_shanahan@hotmail.com,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,To Be Advised,NULL,2 X Twins,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Male,2,Hotels Foreign,NULL,D,Bellingham Travel St Brelade,Superbreaks
1420142,ATE_G1255_20140903152628.CSV,ATE_G1255_20140903152628.CSV,1,00:00.0,13922,Mr,C,C,Bushby,NULL,The Well House,Strait Lane,"Huby, Leeds",West Yorkshire,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,LS67 0EA,633361,L 07050811894,NULL,NULL,5770,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,3,0,0,3,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,LHR,MRU,Longhaul,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,G1255,10,IFON,NULL,NULL,NULL,<No BoardBasis Defined>,bushby@bigfastweb.net,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Mauritius,Le Touessrok,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Mauritius,NULL,NULL,Male,1,Std Package Hol,NULL,D,Number One Travel,If Only Holidays Ltd
468921,AdvantageData 31 August.xlsx,'Baldwins Uckfield$',1,14:41.0,1,Mr.,W,W,Taylor,NULL, Hart Close,Uckfield,East Sussex,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NN22 2DA,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,3058.2,3058.2,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,2,0,0,NULL,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,LHR,MRU,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,7,Enchanting Holidays,NULL,NULL,NULL,All Inclusive,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,N,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Le Meridien Ile Maurice,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Mauritius,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
760382,ATE_33466_20140902043502.CSV,ATE_33466_20140902043502.CSV,1,00:00.0,3,Mr,I,I,Test,NULL,Test,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,0,0,1,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,<No Type Defined>,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,33466,NULL,RAIE,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Male,1,Motorail,NULL,D,Travelwise Handforth,French Motorail
769599,ATE_2585X_20140903154534.CSV,ATE_2585X_20140903154534.CSV,1,00:00.0,1,Mr,D,D,Keenan,NULL, Redcar Drive,Eastham,Wirral,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,CP62 8PE,01515130466-Daniel,NULL,NULL,NULL,1900,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,0,0,2,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Cruise,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2585X,NULL,PAGE,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Male,1,Cruise,NULL,D,Dalton Travel Dunmow,Page & Moy Ltd
1535988,ATE_81633_20140902043127.CSV,ATE_81633_20140902043127.CSV,1,00:00.0,823,Mrs,W,W,Fairhurst,NULL,Chapel House,Arkholme,CARNFORTH,Lancashire,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,LA6  6AX,015848 81454,NULL,NULL,NULL,71.9,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,0,0,1,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,<No Type Defined>,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,81633,NULL,RAIL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Female,1,Rail Ticket,NULL,D,Gates Travel Kendal,ATOC
1910689,ATE_68605_20140903155212.CSV,ATE_68605_20140903155212.CSV,1,00:00.0,46357,Mr,Jonathan,W,Brady,NULL, Lynden Gate Park,Portadown,NULL,Co Armagh,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,BN63 5YP,6610804168,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,0,0,2,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,BFS,<No Dest D,Summer Sun,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,68605,2,SOLU,NULL,NULL,NULL,<No BoardBasis Defined>,NULL,NULL,3,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Alton Towers,Best Western Moathouse,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Male,2,Package/Ft Only,NULL,D,Terra Travel Lurgan,Travel Solutions
1943852,ATE_61659_20140903154707.CSV,ATE_61659_20140903154707.CSV,1,00:00.0,1,Mr,N,N,Express,NULL,.,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,0,0,1,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,National Xpress,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,61659,NULL,NEX,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Male,6,Miscellaneous,NULL,D,AirViceroy,National Express
206859,ATE_75543_20140807124842.CSV,ATE_75543_20140807124842.CSV,1,00:00.0,168,Mrs,K,K,Scott,NULL, Twining Avenue,Twickenham,Middlesex,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NW2 5LP,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,3,0,0,3,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,LGW,IST,Summer Sun,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,75543,7,PLAN,NULL,NULL,NULL,<No Board Basis Defined>,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Limassol,Blue Crane Apts,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Turkey,NULL,NULL,Female,1,Std Package Hol,NULL,D,Thames Travel,Planet  Holidays
207037,ATE_P5549_20140903153751.CSV,ATE_P5549_20140903153751.CSV,1,00:00.0,41813,Mr,S,S,Rawson,NULL, Wike Ridge Mount,Leeds,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,LS67 9NP,6984916306,NULL,NULL,NULL,1040.6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,0,0,1,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,MAN,MEL,<No Type Defined>,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,P5549,NULL,JSET,NULL,NULL,NULL,.,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Australia,NULL,NULL,Male,1,Consolidation,NULL,D,Top Choice Holidays,Jetset Tours
226820,ATE_P6140_20140902041603.CSV,ATE_P6140_20140902041603.CSV,1,00:00.0,1548,Mrs,K,K,Kells,NULL,Granville House,Barrack Lane,Lilleshall,Nr Newport Shropshire,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NF60 9ER,1958666661,NULL,TRUE,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,0,0,2,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Summer Sun,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,P6140,7,THOS,NULL,NULL,NULL,<No BoardBasis Defined>,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Breadsall,Priory,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Female,2,Package Holiday,NULL,D,Roma Travel Keyworth,Thomas Cook Group Ltd
237560,ATE_P6603_20140903154136.CSV,ATE_P6603_20140903154136.CSV,1,00:00.0,59664,Mrs,Jayne,W,Yeomans,NULL,Oswestry,NULL,NULL,Shropshire,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SY66 2LW,1691658111,7763979418,NULL,NULL,1612,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,0,0,2,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,MAN,PFO,Summer Sun,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,P6603,7,THOM,NULL,NULL,NULL,<No BoardBasis Defined>,jayne4467yeomans@aol.com,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Paphos,Louis Phaethon Beach Club,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Cyprus,NULL,NULL,Female,1,Package Holiday,NULL,D,PolkaDot Travel,Thomson Holidays Ltd
249315,ATE_K5624_20140902043254.CSV,ATE_K5624_20140902043254.CSV,1,00:00.0,216,Mr,EW,EW,Murray,NULL,a Linton Close,Newark,NULL,Notts,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NG244NQ,666146,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,2,0,4,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Coach Tours Uk,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,K5624,4,TRWH,NULL,NULL,NULL,<No BoardBasis Defined>,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Skegness Contra,De Vere Mottram Hall Hotel,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Male,2,Std Package Hol,NULL,D,Roma - Newark,Travel Wright Ltd
263146,ATE_P6621_20140903153607.CSV,ATE_P6621_20140903153607.CSV,1,00:00.0,34393,Mrs,A,A,White,NULL, Glen Rise,Belfast,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,BN5 7LF,8890940015,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,0,0,2,NULL,00:00.0,NULL,BFS,SYD,<No Type Defined>,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,P6621,NULL,BSP,NULL,NULL,NULL,<No Board Basis Defined>,markana@virginmedia.com,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Australia,NULL,NULL,Female,1,Air Tickets,NULL,E,Breakaway Travel Shankill Road Belfast,B S P ( U K )
```

### script to change the data types:

```
         
SELECT CAST([IdentityValue] as bigint)[IdentityValue]
      ,[FileName]
      ,[SheetName]
      ,CAST([LineNum] AS INT) [LineNum]
      ,CAST([BookingDate] AS INT) [BookingDate]
      ,CAST([URN] AS INT) [URN]
      ,[Title]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[Initial]
      ,[Surname]
      ,[NameLine]
      ,[Addr1]
      ,[Addr2]
      ,[Addr3]
      ,[Addr4]
      ,[Addr5]
      ,[HouseNo]
      ,[City]
      ,[County]
      ,[Postcode]
      ,[TelNo1]
      ,[TelNo2]
      ,[DPA1]
      ,[DPA2]
      ,CAST([TotalCost] AS MONEY) [TotalCost]
      ,CAST([NettCost] AS MONEY) [NettCost]
      ,[Paid]
      ,[Balance]
      ,CAST([Discount] AS MONEY) [Discount]
      ,[Commission]
      ,[PrimaryCode]
      ,CAST([Adults] AS INT) [Adults]
      ,CAST([Children] AS INT) [Children]
      ,CAST([Infants] AS INT) [Infants]
      ,[Pax]
      ,[SEG]
      ,CAST([DepartureDate]
      ,[Month]
      ,[DeparturePoint]
      ,[ArrivalPoint]
      ,[HolidayType]
      ,[TertiaryCode]
      ,[SubTertiaryCode]
      ,[Season]
      ,[HQABTA]
      ,[BranchABTA]
      ,CAST([Duration] AS INT) [Duration]
      ,[Company]
      ,[Clerk]
      ,[FirstRef]
      ,[SecondRef]
      ,[Board]
      ,[EmailAddress]
      ,[Direct]
      ,[Division]
      ,[LeadPaxAge]
      ,[DueDate]
      ,[PreferredMailing]
      ,[Confidential]
      ,[InsuranceNote]
      ,[DOB]
      ,[LastDestination]
      ,[Pax_DOBS]
      ,[PaymentMethods]
      ,[AirportName]
      ,[Resort]
      ,[Hotel]
      ,[HotelLine2]
      ,[RoomType]
      ,[PreviousBookings]
      ,[PreviousTravels]
      ,[DestinationList]
      ,[Tour]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Gender]
      ,[TransactionNo]
      ,[TransactionType]
      ,[BusAcctRef]
      ,[BookingStatus]
      ,[BranchName]
      ,[OperName]
      INTO CustStg
  FROM AdvBookings
```

Comment: SQL Server - Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Please provide table structure, sample data and desired results.  You're attempting to aggregate on fields in your `group by` clause, that doesn't make any sense.  Also, you're negating your `outer join` by including it in your `where` criteria.  To get those `null` values, move that criteria to the `join`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean Im negating my join with the where clause???

Comment: How did you get it into that format @Used_By_Already?

As I have created another script to insert the data into another table and convert the data types to whats needed?

Comment: I just formatted the text to montype font it was already like that in the raw data

Answer (score 0):

Apologies as this is too large for a comment and might not be considered an answer.

Compare these 2 queries: The first of these will not produce any rows whatsoever **unless A.[Res System] = 'Vantage'**

```
select 'use where condition', b.*
FROM AdvBookings B
LEFT JOIN BkgAgentLut A 
      ON B.FileName = A.FileName 
        AND B.SheetName = A.SheetName 
WHERE A.[Res System] = 'Vantage'
;
```

The second of those queries will list all records from AdvBookings even if A.[Res System] = 'Vantage' is not true.

```
select 'use join condition', b.*
FROM AdvBookings B
LEFT JOIN BkgAgentLut A 
      ON B.FileName = A.FileName 
        AND B.SheetName = A.SheetName 
        AND A.[Res System] = 'Vantage'
```

The difference is how the condition is applied. In the first query you have an "implied inner join" because every row HAS TO comply with the where clause. In the second you have a LEFT JOIN with conditions and this does not prohibit rows from being listed from AdvBookings.

---

For the rest of your question you need to provide sample data that will illustrate your problem. I could not find any BUT I was using SQLFiddle and this limits DDL to 8000 characters so I could only get a few rows inserted. Also the datetime information you have provided seems to be only contain time.

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/646fc/5

For the few records I did get inserted I had no specific problem with your query.